# How to connect to SQL Server with accent in name using JDBC driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've been trying to connect a Spring Boot application to my local SQL Server, but since the server name contains an accented character (namely `É`), the connection protocol doesn't seem to allow it.

I have tried specifying the `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` properties, but nothing has worked so far.

Here is the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

#connection using Windows Authentication
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://FLÉK\\MSSQLSERVER02;databasename=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=usname
spring.datasource.password=somepassword
```

And the error message:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host FLï¿½K, named instance mssqlserver02 failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: FLï¿½K". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
```

I can't change the server name since that would require re-installing the server itself. Any ideas what level I should be looking for the solution at, or where should I enable this usage of unicode?

Comment: Change the spring.datasource.url value programmatically. Build it with Java, then store it.

Comment: If the server has a fixed IP address you could use that

Comment: I think sql server is UTF-16LE by default so you could try changing characterEncoding=UTF-8 to characterEncoding=UTF-16

Comment: Can you try spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;

Comment: OR possibly the following.  If either of these work let me know and I will write an answer
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-16LE

Comment: Have you tried using `\u00C9` in the file? You probably saved your `.properties` file as UTF-8. while it is loaded as ISO-8859-1 (which has been the default for `.properties` since Java 1.0).

Comment: Thank you to everyone, I tried all of the properties mentioned above. @ChrisMaggiulli unfortunately neither of those worked, but @MarkRotteveel your approach did, I didn't know that `.properties` used ISO-8859-1 encoding for reading. Please make this an answer so that I could upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `.properties` file are - by default - expected to be in ISO-8859-1 character set, but it looks like you saved as UTF-8. See [`Properties.load(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)):

> Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input byte
> stream. The input stream is in a simple line-oriented format as
> specified in [`load(Reader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) and is assumed to use the ISO 8859-1
> character encoding; that is each byte is one Latin1 character.
> Characters not in Latin1, and certain special characters, are
> represented in keys and elements using Unicode escapes as defined in
> section 3.3 of *The Java™ Language Specification*.

You have two options in Java in general:

1. Explicitly save in ISO-8859-1. This is a very brittle approach, as it only takes an editor automatically 'fixing' things and saving as UTF-8 to reintroduce the problem
2. Use Unicode escapes for characters outside the ASCII range, in this case `\u00c9`.

For Spring specifically, you have a third option

3. Switch to using YAML configuration files, which are UTF-8 by default.

For Java in general, but not for Spring application properties, you also have the option to load the properties-file using `Properties.load(Reader)`, where the reader has been constructed with the right character set of the file.